# Putting multiple ordered items in one record

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to place all bought items of one order in one record. Something like this

```
OrderID    Occupation        Age     Product Name 1   Product Name 2
300        Network Analyst   33      Switches         Hp Laptop
```

For now, my records look like this

```
OrderID    Occupation        Age     Product Name
300        Network Analyst   33      Switches
300        Network Analyst   33      Hp Laptop
```

Initially I have four tables. The Customer Table, Product Table, Order Table and Ordered Product Table.

[image]

I created a view of all the transactions, which basically looks like the second table shown above.

I want it to look like the first table above if possible.

Comment: Could there be more than 2 products?  By the way, your current design is normalized and good, and what you should be using.

Comment: Tim Biegeleisen, yes there could be more than two products, and my current design is good, but my purpose is to make the above design and convert to a csv file for mining Association Rules as transactional data using the apriori algorithm. Now I am really not sure if my current design will help with the training of my model..

Comment: I made my question more specific

Answer (score 0):

Use *conditional* aggregation :

```
select OrderId, Occupation, Age,
       max(case when Seq = 1 then Product end) [Product1],
       max(case when Seq = 2 then Product end) [Product2]
from (select *,
             row_number() over (partition by OrderId, Occupation, Age order by Product) Seq 
      from table t) t1
where Seq in (1,2)
group by OrderId, Occupation, Age;
```

However, this may fail if you are looking  *n* number of product IF so, then you need to go with `PIVOT` with dynamic style.

Comment: I think you got it the other way around. He wants to pivot the product's names.

Comment: @EzLo... Ohhh yes My BAD.

Comment: Wow, some commands I haven't seen before, but I will try this out

Comment: Hmmm, though I see that you aren't selecting anything from the product table, let me get more specific with my question

Comment: Made my question more specific